# What role allows an EC2 user to run aws ec2 authorize-security-group-egress

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to use `aws ec2 authorize-security-group-egress` to have a script on the ec2 instance temporarily (I'll be pairing with revoke) open a port out to a particular IP. However, when I try to run the command it tells me the user isn't authorized to perform that command. The rest of the error message is encrypted, and unfortunately `aws sts decode-authorization-message` is also not authorized so I can't get any more information. I gather I need to go into the web console and give the user a particular IAM role but I haven't been able to find what role that is.

The error message is: `An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.` followed by five lines of junk that is the encrypted remainder of the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, what is a **good practice**, when a script or program executes on an EC2 instance you give permissions to it through [instance roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

In your case, since you want to use `AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress`, the instance role would need to have such permission.

An example of an **inline policy** in an instance role that you could use is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

AWS **SDK and CLI automatically** will use the instance role, thus there are no actions required from you to make use of them.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I wasn't getting that it's an independent permission that doesn't just come with a specific role and must be specifically added.

Answer (score 0):

Also check this,
--group-id (string)

The ID of the security group. You must specify either the security group ID or the security group name in the request. For security groups in a nondefault VPC, you must specify the security group ID.

This is what blocked my user using the --group-name flag because the security group was not in the default VPC.

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/authorize-security-group-ingress.html#options